# Java: Calculate average heap increase per X unit of time from Map<Long, Long>

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have a long running Java service (Jetty/CometD) that has a memory leak (topic for another day), so the heap increases pretty steadily/consistently over time (but different with different builds/settings etc)

I am taking samples of the heap size over time (every 15 minutes or so) and storing them in a HashMap defined like so:

```
// heapSizeMap uses the current timestamp for the key
// and the size of the heap in MB as the val
Map<Long, Long> heapSizeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and the function that is called to add to the map:

```
public void addToHeapMap() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int mb = 1024*1024;

    Long currentHeap = (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb;

    heapSizeMap.put(new Date().getTime(), currentHeap);
}
```

So I have a Map that lets me graph the heap size over time, and the nearly linear growth over time is pretty obvious.

[image: Heap Growth].

My question is what would be the best way to calculate the average rate of change (increase/growth in my case) in heap size as something like X MB per hour (or X MB per Y unit of time)

Currently I'm just sorting the whole data set in javascript and giving some rough estimates, like the change in heap size in the last 24 hours (taking the current heap, minus the heap 24 hours ago), or calculating the change for each hour in the last 24 hours and averaging those etc.

Obviously that can be pretty inaccurate, especially before the heap starts to resize itself before it reaches the initial heap size (using **-Xms512m -Xmx14g** flags), and the swings in heap size are understandably up and down and when the heap is sampled, no real way of knowing if it was just after a GC, just before, or somewhere in the middle (reason I'd like to calculate the avg rate of heap growth like 50 MB per hour or something along those lines).

Is there a simple or semi-standard way of doing this?  Doesn't have to be super accurate, but looking for something better (and Java native) than the current way I'm handling this...  Thanks

Comment: Why not just profile the application and fix the memory leak? I'd say this is a waste of time unless you're creating a product that deals with memory leaks or something related.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) curve fit.  The slope of the resulting line is the MB/time number you want.

Comment: @Kayaman I would love to fix the memory leak, but I've analyzed heap dumps, and used the YourKit profiler to try and identify where the smoking gun is, however I've come up empty so far.  I'm still pretty new to that part of Java development, and can't seem to locate the source of the problem unfortunately.  Though I'm not giving up, but would like to be able to calculate the growth (and hopefully see it get closer and closer to 0 as I fix leaks)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a *linear trend line* or *best fit* line.  These terms will help you google it.

Roughly speaking, you will need to pick an averaging algorithm so as to reduce your series of points to just two points, and then your MB/time number will essentially be the slope of the line that connects those two points.

Your averaging algorithm can be a sliding window algorithm, which is another way of saying that it may be considering, say, only the last N hours of data.

Of course this will be inaccurate, especially in the beginning of your graph, where I see big ups and downs.  But this inaccuracy is a fact of life.  You need to wait for a while so as to have a large enough data set before you can have any accuracy.

Comment: thank you for better google search terms, as I've seen a few ways to describe it.  and you're right in the inaccuracy aspect, especially while the heap has wider swings, which is why I'm seeking a way to get an average rate of increase (over a specified time period, which I'm planning on storing somewhere like redis so I can analyze it later per build/configuration)

Comment: found this class to help get an average line/slope from my data [LinearRegression.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/LinearRegression.java.html).  If I'm feeding it a data set of points (x axis is timestamps in fifteen minute intervals), the slope returned is a double like 18.78  How do you use that slop to calculate/express in terms of MB/time unit... I know that it already is basically in that form, but is that 18.78MB per 15 minutes (the interval of the data points passed into that class)? or is that already per hour?

Comment: The code you linked looks more complicated than I thought it would be.  In any case, I do not know what this 18.78 is;  I cannot figure out how it works by just looking at it, and I cannot / do not want to go through the trouble of running it and coming up with sample data to feed it.  I am afraid you will need to give it some sample data and see what you get.  Give it 5 points ranging from 10 to 60 (that is, 10 unit increments) and see what you get.